# UserControl child fill Window

Tags: wpf, user-controls, window, wpf-controls

I have a UserControl that is a portion of a wpf window.

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <!--some other display elements would be here-->
        <local:MyUserControl x:Name="Foo" Padding="0,42,0,50"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Inside MyUserControl I have an element that is a gallery that is normally hidden, but when visible, it should fill the entire screen.

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <!--main display elements would be here-->
        <Grid Name="Gallery" Visibility="Hidden">
            <Rectangle Fill="Black" Opacity="0.75"/>
            <TextBlock Name="GalleryLabel" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center">Current Image Title</TextBlock>
            <Button Name="CloseGallery" Style="{DynamicResource WhiteTextButton}" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="25" Click="GalleryClose_OnClick">X</Button>
            <Image Name="GalleryImage" Margin="25"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

How can I set the Gallery to fill the entire Window rather than just the UserControl?

I was able to get it to work by adding `Margin="0,-42,0,-50"` to Gallery, but I don't like that solution. I would rather do something that doesn't involve hard-coding values in the UserControl so that I would be able to have more flexiblility in using it.

Normally it looks like:
[image: Normal Window]
where the green Foo area is MyUserControl, and the rest of the things in the window are other elements.

At certain points, I have a gallery display an image, which should fill the entire screen like:
[image]
which should fill the entire screen and have a black opaque overlay, along with an image displayed on top of the overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Padding...

You can use:

```
 <local:MyUserControl x:Name="Foo" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAligment="Stretch"/>
```

**EDIT**

I may admit that I still am not sure what you want. But I made something which does the same as you showed in the pictures. But be aware that this as an opinion based question, and the answer is my opinion, there are a lot of ways to achieve this. And this is only one of them:

**MainWindow**

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:myProject="clr-namespace:MyProject"
    Title="MainWindow" >

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="Gainsboro" Grid.Row="0">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Show gallery" Width="100" Margin="10"/>
            <Button Content="Do something else" Width="150" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <myProject:SomeOtherStuff Grid.Row="1" />

    <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Gainsboro">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="Buttom area, can be used for something else"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <myProject:GalleryUserControl x:Name="GalleryUserControl" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Visibility="Hidden"/>
</Grid>
```

**SomeOtherStuff UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.SomeOtherStuff"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid Background="Green">
    <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="Foo" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Verdana"/>
</Grid>
```

**Gallery UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="XamDataGrid.GalleryUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Height="500" Width="800">
<Grid Background="#99000000">
    <TextBlock Text="Currect image title" Foreground="White" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
    <Button Name="CloseGallery"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Content="X" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="25" Click="GalleryClose_OnClick"/>
    <Image Margin="30"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: The problem with that is now MyUserControl covers the other elements in the window

Comment: Isn't that what you want ??? We can't see what other elements you got there. And you were asking to make it fill the entire Window

Comment: No. I have `<!--some other display elements would be here-->` in the window because the actual elements I have probably aren't helpful and they are subject to change. I was asking specifically for the Gallery to fill the window, not anything else.

Comment: You have to be more clear, as it is right now it's pretty unclear what you want. What is "Gallery" ? According to your code it is the Grid inside your UserControl, which fills the entire UserControl. That's why I assumed you wanted the UserControl to fill your entire Window. I could keep guessing or assuming, but maybe add a drawing or some more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

An `Adorner` will be best for you. As it floats above everything else and remains outside the `VisualTree` too.

[image: Overlay Gallery Control Output]

UserControl2

```
  <UserControl2 ...>
   <Grid>
        <Grid Background="#FF709FA6" Opacity="0.3" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
             Height="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}}">
        </Grid>
        <Grid Width="600" Height="700">
            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF37DAEA" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE84242" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <!-- Gallery controls -->
            <Button Content="Welcome to Gallery" HorizontalAlignment="Left" IsHitTestVisible="True" Margin="112,126,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="68" FontSize="48" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="83,42,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="UserControl2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Foreground="#FF1B0D0D"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </UserControl2>
```

UserControl1

Code :

```
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // get root Window
            DependencyObject current = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(this);
            while (!(current is Window))
                current = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(current);

            Window root = current as Window;

            IEnumerable children = LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root);
            Panel p = null;
            foreach (var child in children)
            {
                p = child as Panel; // get first container panel in Window
                break;
            }

            // Create UserControl2 to add to the adorner
            UserControl2 ctrlGallery = new UserControl2();

            AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(p);
            GalleryAdorner adorner = new GalleryAdorner(p, ctrlGallery);
            layer.Add(adorner);
        }
    }

public class GalleryAdorner : Adorner
    {
        private Control _child;
        VisualCollection collection;

        public GalleryAdorner(UIElement elem, Control child)
            : base(elem)
        {
            collection = new VisualCollection(this);
            _child = child;
            collection.Add(_child);
        }

        protected override int VisualChildrenCount
        {
            get
            {
                return 1;
            }
        }

        protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
        {
            if (index != 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            return collection[0];
        }

        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
        {
            _child.Measure(constraint);
            return _child.DesiredSize;
        }

        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            _child.Arrange(new Rect(new Point(0, 0), finalSize));
            return new Size(_child.ActualWidth, _child.ActualHeight);
        }
    }
```